# Как правильно согласовать в числе существительное после прилагательных, вводимых союзом "как..., так и"?

Tags: согласование

В частности, как правильно: "как на русском, так и (на) английском языке" или "как на русском, так и (на) английском языках"?

Answer (score 1):

Как на русском, так и на английском языках. Или как на русском языке, так и на английском. Как на русском, так и на английском языке
То есть возможны оба варианта. Второй и третий варианты поздазумевают эллипсис, то есть слово язык не повторяется, а подразумевается как на русском языке, так и на английском (языке). Существительное вообще может опускаться.
Как на русском, так и на английском.

Comment: Спасибо, V.V. Это соответствует практике употребления этого оборота в Интернете: практически одинаковое количество у обоих вариантов. Это понятно и логически. Меня, однако, сбило с толку указание Розенталя в разделе "Два определения при одном существительном" (п.4): если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне связаны, напр. "в старославянском и древнерусском книжном языке". Наверное, в нашем случае этой связи нет. Что касается возможности опускания существительного, однако, то я думаю, что в официальном стиле это не рекомендуется.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Теперь я знаю новое русское слово _"эллипсис"_. И то, что английское _"ellipsis"_ может означать как _"многоточие"_, так и собственно _"эллипсис"_.

Comment: Спасибо, поспешишь — людей насмешишь. (Это я про себя)